# Eclipse (XText) SelectionListener registration

Tags: java, eclipse, xtext

I have implemented a view which shall register itself as listner for changes in the XText editor and related outline. To this end I am adding this line

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().addSelectionListener(this);
```

in the createPartControl method of the view (which implements the ISelectionListener interface). In the selectionChanged method I therefore check whether the selection is a ITextSelection, the case in which it comes from the XTextEditor, or an IStructuredSelection, the case in which it come sfrom the Outline.

The problem is that, doing so, when I start Eclipse the outline is said to be "unavailable". If I click on the outline it is refreshed, the contents are shown and the listening view correctly updated.
What am I doing wrong and what should I do to avoid the initial "unavailability" of the outline?

Answer (score 1):

I have been recently faced with this exact problem and have solved it by implementing IPartListener2 in the class that extends ViewPart then adding a part listener in the createPartcontrol method like this :

```
getSite().getWorkbenchWindow().getPartService().addPartListener(this);
```

Now by using something like this in your partOpened method (that has to be implemented before you can actually use the part listener you will get the view contents to be avaiable initially :

```
public void partOpened(IWorkbenchPartReference partRef) {

    if(partRef.getPage().getActiveEditor() instanceof XtextEditor) {
        somepart=partRef.getPage().getActiveEditor();
        final XtextEditor editor = (XtextEditor)somepart;
        final IXtextDocument document = editor.getDocument();
        document.readOnly(new IUnitOfWork.Void<XtextResource>(){
            public void process (XtextResource resource) throws Exception {
                IParseResult parseResult = resource.getParseResult();
                if(parseResult ==null)
                    return;
            CompositeNode rootNode=(CompositeNode) parseResult.getRootNode();
            LeafNode node = (LeafNode)NodeModelUtils.findLeafNodeAtOffset(rootNode, 0);
            EObject object =NodeModelUtils.findActualSemanticObjectFor(node);
            view.setInput(object);
            }
            });
        }
}
```

this will make the view you're implementing get it's contents when you activate the XtextEditor (that is specific to your DSL). 
In order to make the view change contents in real time as you change anything in the file active in the editor you should implement an IDocumentListener and override the DocumentChanged method. If you do this you won't be dependant on the SelectionListener anymore because the view should update automatically when something changes in your document

Hope this helps!